# Raspberry: Showing various images on display according to GPIO states

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I would like to have some advice, what would be the best solution to my problem. I want to write a python program, that runs on Raspberry Pi. It runs in an infinite loop, and checks various stuff, like contents of some folders, and GPIO states.

A basic operation looks like this:

1. pictures arrive in a folder from a different source
2. the code notices, reads the images, does some processing
3. it starts to listen to GPIO input: in case of GPIO state change, the code displays the image.
4. if the GPIO state changes again, the code switches the picture to an another. And the loop resets, files are deleted, and the cycle starts again

I solved most of the problems, but I have difficulties with displaying the images.

I tried using opencv, I structured the code something like this, it's only a dummy:

```
state = "first_phase"

while True:    
   state = decide_state() #this part checks everything,
                           GPIO, folders, etc
 
   if state = "first_phase":
      cv2.imread(some_picture)
      cv2.imshow(the picture)
      cv2.waitKey(1500) #I had freezes with less delay, but this seems to work
      state = "next_phase"
      continue    
   elif state = "next_phase":
      cv2.imread(some_other_picture)
      cv2.imshow(the_picture)
      cv2.waitKey(1500)
      state = "first_phase"
      continue

destroyAllWindows()
```

This is much much more complex in reality, with way more states and GPIO ports used, it really is a difficult application, but the idea is something like this, and it is working. 99% of the time...

1% of the time I get weird errors, like "GDK_IS_DEVICE" and Segmentation Faults. (I checked, resources are ok) I can't resolve them, and they come erratically, sometimes right away, sometimes after the 994th picture, and always at the point where the code tries to show the images.

I'm now convinced that it has to do with the highgui opencv uses, but - you can probably guess from my code - I have not enough experience to debug this. I cannot completely omit using opencv because I'll also do some operations on the images, but for displaying them I think I should use an another method. PILLOW is not okay, because I don't want to write out the results of the image manipulations, only draw them on the display. (also it is only possible to kill the display with subprocesses, and I don't feel comfortable doing that). I tried using tkinter but I'm lost how threading and communicating between my main loop and the tkinter loop would be possible and crash-free.

I can restart the code, but the last images will be lost, and it is important to show them again, if the code crashed. I could write a workaround, where I write the manipulated pictures on the disk, and after a successfull display it deletes them, so after starting up again, it sees that there are still images left to show, and shows them... but this only solves the symptoms, and also kills the sd card faster.

Is there any other solution to this? TL;DR: I want to draw pictures on the display in case of some events, while my code does it's thing in the background for eternity.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: (Window: 18832): Gdk-CRITICAL **:12:44:27.666: gdk_device_get_n_axes: assertation GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Segmentation fault  -- Something like this, it varies, and sometimes I got 4-5 from these at once, sometimes less

Comment: please come up with a complete minimal reproducible example for the error. that means you strip out everything that isn't absolutely required to demonstrate the error. and put that error message in your post.